# Por que as "aspas" nos dados INT?

Tags: mysql

No *MySQL Workbench*, quando não inserimos um registro por *query*, e sim manualmente, ao dar o *APPLY*, a *query* é exibida antes da execução.

Exemplo de uma *query* composta pelo *MySQL Workbench*:

```
INSERT INTO `nomedobanco`.`tabela` (`id`, `resumo`, `descricao`, `grupo`, `solicitante`, `atendente`, `status`) 
VALUES ('171', 'Teste', 'Testando', '7', '1', '2', 'N');
```

Como também funcionaria:

```
INSERT INTO `nomedobanco`.`tabela` (`id`, `resumo`, `descricao`, `grupo`, `solicitante`, `atendente`, `status`) 
VALUES (171, 'Teste', 'Testando', 7, 1, 2, 'N');
```

---

#### Dúvidas

- Por que o *MySQL Workbench* coloca aspas nos valores *INT*?

  - Ele não identifica o tipo dos campos e acaba inserindo tudo "como string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente isso não é uma exclusividade do `Workbench`. Utilizei outras ferramentas e o `SqlYog` por exemplo, faz exatamante a mesma coisa.

Isso é para otimizar a geração da `query`. Como o `MySql` não reclama de receber valores inteiros entre aspas, esses programas utilizam desse artificio para não precisar verificar o tipo da coluna para colocar ou não o valor entre as aspas.

Mas tome cuidado ao utilizar esse artificio. No caso de `INSERT` e no `SET` do `UPDATE`, ou seja, atribuições, não vejo tanto problema. Mas no `WHERE` você pode ter alguns problemas relacionados a desempenho da `query`. Isso porque, ao comparar texto com número, o `MySql` executa uma conversão de tipos, então nesses casos, o ideal é utilizar números sem aspas, se, comparados com números.

> Observe que o `Workbench` também coloca os valores numéricos entre aspas nas comparações.

No `INSERT` ele provavelmente também executa essa conversão, mas, como a quantidade de dados geralmente é pequena se torna irrelevante (não é verdade para todos os casos).